# How to start an sql job by completion of other sql Jobs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-job

I have 5 sql jobs. But I have to start the 5th sql job only when all other 4 sql jobs are been completed. Is it possible to achieve it?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Do you need separate jobs? You could do 1 job with multiple steps, they will execute sequentially.

Comment: I need separate jobs. Because I am starting the first four jobs at same time to save time all together.

Comment: Interesting, as you may not know the order in which the first 4 jobs finished, my idea would be to write a log into a table at the end of the execution of each of the first 4 jobs, then execute the 5th only when you have the execution of the rest.

Comment: Something like:
- At the end of each of the first 4 Sps insert into logTable.
- Check log table if all 4 SPs where executed.
- If no, do nothing.
- If yes, exec 5th job

Answer (score 1):

You could organize your jobs in a [maintenance plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/maintenance-plans).

Add nodes for each job and link the first four jobs to the fifth job (drag the arrow under the node). Right click the link between the jobs and select "completion". The fifth job will now wait until all previous jobs are finished executing.

Triggering the maintenance plan (either ad-hoc or with a schedule) will start parallel execution of the nodes without dependencies.

[image: maintenance plan]